# Is it possible to use react librararies for Microsoft azure ad b2c for 'react-native' as well?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, azure-ad-b2c

Curently I have a need to connect a **'react-native'** app to **Microsoft's Azure Ad B2C**. There are a few libraries out there that are written specifcally for react-native, but I was wondering if it is possible to use reat libraries made for azure ad b2c for a react-native app as well.
And if it is not possible, what's the reason for it.
Thanks

Comment: please refer to this  similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62126002/azure-ad-b2c-with-react-native-expo/62160591?) it may help you

Comment: please refer to https://github.com/sonyarouje/react-native-ad-b2c